# stack corruption by eliminate a printf()

Tags: c, runtime-error

some time ago I tried to program a Mergesort. In some point I got an error that I was able to solve, but still saved the code because have something strange that i don't understand. The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef int elem;

void mergesort(elem * arr, unsigned n){
    if(n != 1){
        if(n == 2){
            if(arr[0] > arr[1]){
                int change = arr[0];
                arr[0] = arr[1];
                arr[1] = change;
            }
        }else{
            unsigned i = 0, j = 0, mit = (n+1)>>2, fin = n>>2;
            elem * arr_2 = (elem *)malloc(sizeof(elem) * n), * mit_arr = arr+mit;
            mergesort(arr, mit);
            mergesort(mit_arr, fin);
            while(i < mit || j < fin){
                if(arr[i] <= mit_arr[j]){
                    arr_2[j+i] = arr[i];
                    i++;
                }else{
                    arr_2[j+i] = mit_arr[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                arr[i] = arr_2[i];
            free(arr_2);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned a = 10;
    int i;
    elem * arr = (elem*)malloc(sizeof(elem) * a);
    arr[0] = 12;
    arr[1] = 3;
    arr[2] = -3;
    arr[3] = 22;
    arr[4] = 12;
    arr[5] = 11;
    arr[6] = 4;
    arr[7] = 9;
    arr[8] = 10;
    arr[9] = 2;
    printf("something\n");     // 1
    mergesort(arr, a);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<a; i++){
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that, despite the fact that the code doesn't do what I want and it seems like there is no error, if I comment out the line marked by 1 (`printf("something\\n");` ) then the error "`malloc(): corrupted top size`" appears. I actually don't know why something like that is possible, so I came here to see if someone have an explanation.

I tried to debug the program with `gdb` and got the same error, but have more information:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

but still without idea of what happened.

Comment: This is not C++. This is C.

Comment: You have a buffer overflow. https://godbolt.org/z/v8d7T83Mv

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/a1s4G1GfE shows a buffer overflow in the merge operation. The merge does not look like a typical merge. You are doing `while(i < mit || j < fin)` and inside that loop you assume both `i` and `j` are in the correct range. That's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of major issues with your code. These are things you should be able to test yourself by checking whether the values being used by your function are what you expect.

Here's the first issue. You have calculated the length of the first half of the array as `(n+1)>>2`, and then you assume the length of the remaining array is `n>>2`. That is simply not true. Shifting a value to the right by 2 binary places is a *division by four*.

It is far better to use "normal" math instead of attempting to be clever. This reduces the chance for errors, and makes your code easier to read.

```
unsigned mit = n / 2, fin = n - mit;
```

The other issue is your merge. You have made your while-loop run until *both* `i` and `j` are out-of-range. But in your loop, it's guaranteed that on at least one of the iterations, one of those values *will* be out-of-range.

A better way to merge arrays uses *three* loops. The first one runs until *either* of the arrays has been merged in, and the remaining two loops will copy the remaining part of the other array.

```
unsigned x = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
while(i < mit && j < fin){
    if(arr[i] <= mit_arr[j]){
        arr_2[x++] = arr[i++];
    }else{
        arr_2[x++] = mit_arr[j++];
    }
}
while(i < mit){
    arr_2[x++] = arr[i++];
}
while(j < fin){
    arr_2[x++] = mit_arr[j++];
}
```

Comment: I've probably done something wrong (I plugged your 3-loop version in OP's code), but the sorting doesn't seem to produce the expected result: https://godbolt.org/z/54b9vh8Gz

Comment: Well, you also removed the part that copies the merged array back to the original.

Comment: ...and that's why I should have my coffee *before* I touch my laptop :)

Comment: Thanks for clarify, but what I want to know is not about the code errors (because I already solve it) but the fact that the error disappear if I comment out the marked line.

Comment: (at least, when I compile it with `gcc`)

Comment: Accessing memory beyond what's actually available to your program is undefined behavior. Most times when you have a problem that mysteriously disappears due to adding/removing a `printf`, it's due to undefined behavior. I already explained that your for-loop potentially accesses memory of the end of your arrays. Adding the GCC option `-fsanitize=address` will help you troubleshoot memory issues.